# Enviar array desde android

Tags: android, android-studio

como puedo crear un array de los siguientes objetos en Android.
por `Postman` puedo enviarlos sin problema pero como quedaría del lado de `Android`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como podría hacer esto en `Android Studio`.

Comment: Porque no comentas como los recibiría Android, que formato ?

Comment: no los recibe, los envia, quiero enviar los parámetros tal cual esta en postman pero no se como seria en android

Comment: ok Manuel, entonces imagino que solo envias estos valores en un POST o GET?

Comment: asi es, van por POST

Comment: En android agrega como obtienes los valores que muestras, eso ya lo tienes?

Comment: no, no importa que sean datos estáticos, solo quiero saber como puedo hacer una colección de esos elementos

Comment: si son CheckBox, una forma sería un StringBuilder con append